# Why cannot I see RSS feeds in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rss, feed-reader

Why cannot I see RSS feeds in Outlook 2010? I want all RSS feeds in one unified folder, so I have added my subscription to the predefined RSS folder.

[image]

However, this predefined RSS folder continues to show me the splash screen.

[image]

You can see the notification for 50 unread feeds in the above screenshot. Where can I see these unread feeds?

Answer (score 4):

Go to RSS folder properties.

[image]

Disable home page.

[image]